# Passing structure over a Socket from client to server

Tags: c, client-server, structure

I need  to code for uploading a file from client to server.

In client side, i have declared a structure,

```
typedef struct upload_file
{
 char *filename;
 char *filebuffer;
}upload_file;
```

I am getting filename from command line argument.

In main function, I am assigning the file name with structure variable.

```
upload_file.filename = argv[1];
```

Then I am reading the file content, putting into a buffer & copying that to structure's buffer value.

```
strcpy(upld.buffer,tmp); //tmp is a buffer which will contain the file content
```

After that I am writing the structure into socket as follows,

```
 write(sd, &upld, sizeof(upld));
```

This part is fine with the client side. In the server side if I read the whole structure & how do i separate the file content & file name?

Also , the buffer value (i.e file content ) from client side is malloced & could it be available to server side?

How do to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a structure with pointers in it is useless. The pointers themselves will be sent across but *not* the things they point to.

What you need to do is marshal the data for transmission, something which the various RPC mechanisms (OPC, DCE, etc) do quite well.

If you *can't* use an established method like that, it's basically a matter of going through the structure element by element, copying the *targets* into a destination buffer.

For example, with the structure:

```
struct person {
    int age;
    char *name;
    char *addr;
} p;
```

you could do something like:

```
msgbuff = outbuff = malloc (
    sizeof (int) +
    strlen (p.name) + 1 +
    strlen (p.addr) + 1
    );
if (msgbuff != NULL) {
    *((int*)outbuff) = p.age;  outbuf += sizeof (p.age);
    strcpy (outbuff, p.name) ; outbuf += strlen (p.name) + 1;
    strcpy (outbuff, p.addr) ; outbuf += strlen (p.addr) + 1;
    // Send msgbuff
    free (msgbuff);
} else {
    // Some error condition.
}
```

Note that an `int` is transferred directly since it's *in* the structure. For the character pointers (C strings), you have to get at the target of the pointer rather than the pointer itself.

Essentially, you transform:

```
p:  age  (46)
    name (0x11111111)  -->  0x11111111: "paxdiablo"
    addr (0x22222222)  -->  0x22222222: "Circle 9, Hades"
   |--------------------|-------------------------------|
    structure memory <- | -> other memory
```

into:

```
msgbuff (0x88888888) -> {age}{"paxdiablo"}{"Circle 9, Hades"}
```

This complicates the process a little since you also have to unmarshal at the other end, and you'll need to watch out for system that have different sized `int` types. But that's basically how it's done.

Comment: Aren't you writing p.name over the p.age when serializing data into outbuff?

Comment: I think `outbuff += sizeof(int)` needs to be added after writing `p.age`.

Comment: Yes, both right, I originally had the age last so it wasn't needed but changed it to take care of potential alignment issues. Fixed now, thanks.